# Refine my code/program where did I go wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int LordIronhead = 0; 
    char answer;

    cout<<"Is Lord Ironhead present? Y/N.\n";
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 'Y')
    {
        LordIronhead=0;
    }
    else if (answer == 'N')
    {
        LordIronhead= LordIronhead+1;
    }

    cout<< ""<<LordIronhead<<"\n"; 

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run the program and If I answer NO (N) 
the result is always 0 instead of 1 (LordIronhead = LordIronhead + 1)

May I know where my error is?

Comment: the program seems to work on [ideone](http://ideone.com/dMO3ET)

Comment: Your code works for me.  Just a guess but since the answer is case sensitive - are you sure you're entering 'N' rather than 'n' in your tests?

Comment: Probably not in the code you posted... At least, it works on my machine.

Comment: What have you tried? Chop it down to minimal assumptions. E.g. comparing `char`. Or do you type a capital `N`, what about lowercase, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you enter a capital N?

Comment: For other peoples benefit's, what was your mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine in principle, but you might run into issues with the two-valued logic of 'answer' being checked against 'Y' and against 'N' with no fall-through case. I suspect you are running into EOL or case or character conversion issues, falling through both if's and thereby never changing the Lord.

For showing the problem, try an else statement:

```
else if (answer == 'N')
{
     LordIronhead= LordIronhead+1;
} else {
     std::cout << "Invalid answer '" << answer << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct but is sensitive to the case of user input (it treats user input of `N` and `n` differently).  You'd remove a possible source of user confusion by converting the input to a known case before checking it.  You can do this using either [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) or [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)

```
cin >> answer;
answer = toupper(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this myself and found that if I answered N I got the expected answer (1). If I hit n, however, it came back as 0. Are you sure you're hitting N and not n?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please don't use the answer section to put comments, use the **comment** section instead

Answer (score 0):

Better using 1 and 0 instead of N and Y. Its more recognizable to the system

Comment: sure but in other languages for example Chars can be readout as string (if Vaariable.equals("examplestring")) and a == is only possible by integers (if Variable == exampleInt) sometimes this is a trap, where you never find out on your own.